# How do I split an address string in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, string

I want to split a column into 4 columns based on column.

Eg:  column value includes 'City_Name' , 'State' ,Zipcode' ,'Country'

I want to split it into 4 different columns like `City_Name`, `State`, `Zipcode`, `Country`.

How can I do this using T-SQL?

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using? Also, please use a more descriptive title: something like 'How do I split an address string in T-SQL'?

Comment: Please provide a sample of what the source column looks like. The exact formatting is important.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply...i am using SQL Sever 2005...Source column Name is Details and value is 'Delhi , Delhi ,34567 ,IND' Now the o/p should should look like

City_Name   State   Zipcode  Country
--------------------------------------
Delhi       Delhi   34567     IND

Answer (score 8):

assuming you always have 3 commas in that column you can use the [PARSENAME](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Ten_SQL_Server_Functions_That_You_Have_Ignored_Until_Now#PARSENAME) function

```
create table #test(Col varchar(100))
insert #test values('City_Name,State,Zipcode,Country')
insert #test values('New York City,NJ,10028,United States')


select parsename(replace(Col,',','.'),4) as City_Name,
parsename(replace(Col,',','.'),3) as State,
parsename(replace(Col,',','.'),2) as Zipcode,
parsename(replace(Col,',','.'),1) as Country
from #test
```

output

```
City_Name   State   Zipcode Country
New York City   NJ  10028   United States
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've got some obvious separators in your original column, you can either write a user-defined function or use some inline regex to extract your data into 4 columns. How you do that depends on:

- your data and especially how homogeneous it is
- your RDMBS

You may want to let us see some sample data for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

step 1: create the four new columns in your database table.  since you're adding new columns to an existing table, they have to have default values (for example, the empty string)

step 2: run an update query that updates your four new columns based on your old column.  Use the SQL string functions to do this (can look them up in the reference, for example, [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx))

step 3: drop the old column

Comment: Thanks for the reply ...Since i am using both SUBSTRING and CHARIINDEX
But i am able to split it  into  two columns the sample query which am working  is looks like 

SELECT SUBSTRING(CITY,1,CHARINDEX(',',CITY)) AS CITY_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME

This will give as only City Name ..i need for the rest of other colums also 

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table with the desired fields. Traverse through the records in the original table and split the value in that one column by the delimiter. For splitting, you could use charindex, substring and other string manipulation functions. You can code this logic in a SP or a function.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with your sample string:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_PARM (@Parm nvarchar(2000))
RETURNS @TParm TABLE (City_Name nvarchar(100),State nvarchar(100),Zipcode nvarchar(100),Country nvarchar(100)) 
AS  
BEGIN 

DECLARE @City_Name nvarchar(100)
    ,@State nvarchar(100)
    ,@Zipcode nvarchar(100)
    ,@Country nvarchar(100)
    ,@CommaPosition1 tinyint
    ,@CommaPosition2 tinyint

    SELECT @CommaPosition1 = charindex(',',@Parm)
    IF (@CommaPosition1>0) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @City_Name = ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING(@Parm,1,@CommaPosition1 - 1)))
        SELECT @CommaPosition2 = @CommaPosition1 + 1

        SELECT @CommaPosition1 = charindex(',',@Parm,@CommaPosition2)
        IF (@CommaPosition1>0) 
        BEGIN
            SELECT @State = ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING(@Parm,@CommaPosition2 + 1,@CommaPosition1 - (@CommaPosition2 + 1))))
            SELECT @CommaPosition2 = @CommaPosition1 + 1

            SELECT @CommaPosition1 = charindex(',',@Parm,@CommaPosition2)
            IF (@CommaPosition1>0) 
            BEGIN
                SELECT @Zipcode = ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING(@Parm,@CommaPosition2 + 1,@CommaPosition1 - (@CommaPosition2 + 1))))
                SELECT @Country = ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING(@Parm,@CommaPosition1 + 1,LEN(@Parm))))
            END
        END
    END

    INSERT INTO @TParm (City_Name, State, Zipcode,Country) 
        VALUES (@City_Name, @State, @Zipcode, @Country)

    RETURN 
END 
GO
```

Simple usage:

```
select * from fn_PARM('Delhi , Delhi ,34567 ,IND' )
```

For use in a query, see **[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx)** about using APPLY.